# how to scan an array of complex number in C

Tags: c

```
int input,n,i;
    scanf("%d%d",&input,&n);
    double a,b;
    double complex arr[n];

      for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
      {
         scanf("%lf%lf",&a,&b);
         creal(arr[i])=a;
         cimag(arr[i])=b;
       }
```

error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment`enter code here`
        creal(arr[i])=a;
why can't I take input for an array of complex number

Comment: What are `creal` and `cimage`?

Comment: Oh wait, do you mean [these](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/complex/creal)?

Comment: `arr[i] = CMPLX(a, b);`

Comment: Hmmm ... `arr[i] = a + b * I;`? ([7.3.1p6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.3.1p6) if `I` has not been undefined/redefined)

Answer (score 0):

According to [6.2.5p13](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p13), you can do (not tested!)

```
double complex a[42];
double tmp[2];
tmp[0] = 3.14159;
tmp[1] = -2.71828;
memmove(a + 3, tmp, sizeof tmp); // a[3] = 3.14159 - 2.71828i
```

Comment: Instead of the direct assignment, you could certainly do: `if (scanf("%lf%lf", tmp, tmp + 1) != 2) /* error */;`